# Adding Convenience Functions in Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I just started playing around with Firebase/Javascript and happily was able to stand up functionality very quickly. I have found lots of online examples to get started, but haven't been able to find one that addresses the following scenario. The context is a mobile app that will be logging events via a single web-hook-like API using this construction:

```
exports.processEvent = functions.firestore.document('Events/{eventId}').onCreate(event => { 
    console.log('>>>>> Event triage triggered');
    // grab the eventType and the payload to determine delegation path
    const eventType = event.get("eventType");
    const eventPayload = event.get("payload");

    // delegate to the correct event handler
    switch (eventType) {
        case "ORDER":
            console.log("=> Event:ORDER received: ", eventPayload);
            handleOrderEvent(eventPayload);
            break;
        case "SHIP":
            console.log("=> Event:SHIP received: ", eventPayload);
            handleShipEvent(eventPayload);
            break;
        default:
            console.error("=> Event:UNKNOWN received: ", eventPayload);
    }
    return true;
});
```

And I define the handler function as:

```
exports.handleOrderEvent = function handleOrderEvent(payload) {
    const orderDB = firestore.collection("Orders");

    // Add the new order to the database
    orderDB.add(payload)
    .then(function(docRef) {
        console.log("Created new Order: ", docRef.id);
        return;
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.error("Error adding Order:", error);
        return;
    });
 };
```

But, at runtime I get the following error:

```
ReferenceError: handleOrderEvent is not defined
```

I just don't want to have a gigantic switch() statement inside the processEvent() function, so was trying to decompose it into more manageable chunks.

What am I missing in the declaration of the handler function that prevents the processEvent() function from being able to find it? I have tried placing it above the processEvent() function in the index.js file. I have just declared the function without attaching it to exports.  I am sure it is something basic?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your exports are automatically available to the local file. So this might work better:

```
function handleOrderEvent(payload) {
    const orderDB = firestore.collection("Orders");

    // Add the new order to the database
    orderDB.add(payload)
    .then(function(docRef) {
        console.log("Created new Order: ", docRef.id);
        return;
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.error("Error adding Order:", error);
        return;
    });
 };
exports.handleOrderEvent = handleOrderEvent;
```

So this first defined the `handleOrderEvent` function, that you call from the `processEvent` export. It then also exports `handleOrderEvent`, so other scripts (or Cloud Functions clients) can call it. If you don't need the latter, you can simply remove that last line.

Comment: Frank - thank you! I implemented as suggested, without the last line, and it is working as expected now. I did have to deploy it twice - perhaps just too impatient on my part. Very much appreciated!